# Is it possible to remove AOT assemblies from third-party .apk?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk

I have a third-party apk that I'm trying to optimize, as the developer couldn't be bothered with such petty things.

The application is built with Xamarin and contains AOT assemblies. Is there a way to strip them from the apk without completely reverse-engineering the project and building it anew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing AOT assemblies from an .apk is as easy as deleting them and correctly re-signing the package.

Here are the steps:

- Open the .apk as zip file, delete `lib\<architecture>\libaot-*.so` files.
  Xamarin apps include `libmonodroid.so` and `libmonosgen-2.0.so` even without AOT compilation, don't touch those.
- Delete META-INF from root of the .apk.
- Sign the resulting .apk using `jarsigner` from the JDK. If you don't have the original key, any will do, you will just lose the ability to update the app automatically.
- Don't forget to align the .apk with `zipalign` from Android build tools.

Resulting thinner app installs and runs perfectly, but will, of course take a couple of seconds longer to launch.